Hyperparameter Tuning with MERF doesnt work - fit function only takes two arguments but the function requires more
I am trying to perform nested cross-validation using Mixed Effects Random Forests (MERF). However, I’ve encountered an issue: the fit function of RandomizedSearchCV only accepts two arguments (X and y), whereas the MERF model requires four arguments (X, Z, cluster, and y).
This discrepancy is preventing me from implementing nested cross-validation successfully. Does anyone have suggestions on how to modify the workflow to accommodate passing more than two arguments to the fit function?
model = MERF()
search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, random_grid, n_iter=10, cv=inner_cv, refit=True, scoring = 'r2', n_jobs=-1,random_state=42)
result = search.fit(X= X_train, Z=Z_values_train, clusters=ID_train,y=y_train)
